# How to compress a list of sorted words?

Tags: algorithm, compression

I have a large file with a single word per line. The entire file is sorted and I now need to compress it. I could simply use GZIP and the result would be pretty good. However I am wondering if it is possible to do better knowing that we are dealing with a list of sorted words.

Here's a snippet of my list of sorted words:

```
[...]
ABAISSAT
ABAISSATES
ABAISSE
ABAISSEE
ABAISSEES
ABAISSEMENT
ABAISSEMENTS
ABAISSENT
ABAISSER
ABAISSERA
ABAISSERAI
ABAISSERAIENT
ABAISSERAIS
[...]
```

Would compressing the file using prefixes give a better results then GZIP?

```
[...]
ABAISS AT ATES E EE EES EMENT EMENTS ENT ER ERA ERAI ERAIENT ERAIS
[...]
```

What is the algoritm that would allow me to compress my list of words using the sort of compression I am describing? Any other idea how I could compress the data?

P.S. I though about using a Trie and I implemented it. The final size of the Trie is memory was almost as large as the list itself and the time to load the list was very high. For these reasons I decided to no go that path.

Comment: You can try, but usually, it will not be better, or marginally better than what GZIP can achieve.

Comment: For what purpose do you wish to compress the file?  Are you simply looking to save disk space?  Are you looking to manipulate the compressed structure programmatically?  What is the goal?

Comment: Bzip and 7zip usually give better compression rates than gzip.

Comment: The goal is that the file must be as small as possible since it will end up on a mobile device.

Comment: What size does gzip/bzip result in? Is this not small enough? If not, how much smaller does it need to be? Also, since it's a mobile device, what about runtime overheads? I could imagine a *slightly larger* file that had less runtime requirements (or other properties such as "word searchability") could be advantageous .. that is an array-based trie (one that does *not* need to be loaded entirely) might be "better", for instance.

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be thinking of something like [front compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_encoding), where each entry is a count of the number of leftmost characters which the entry shares with the preceding entry followed by the remaining, unshared characters. Example using your data:

```
0, ABAISSAT
8, ES
6, E
7, E
etc.
```

The result would still need gzipping (or other compression).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function to calculate the difference between two consecutive words, apply that to the whole list and GZIP compress that (also, you'd need to save the first word as the starting point).

What would the function look like?  Not sure, you'd have to experiment with that.

The idea is that the difference between consecutive words would be small (in terms of information).

This is kind of the same concept idea used in video compression (one of the techniques, anyway) - that consecutive frames will be very similar.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/523785/627806 which suggests a similar algorithm applied to integers.  Clearly, it's easier to decide on a function to find the difference between two integers than between two strings though.